# Global Model not found

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, kats

When I try running the tutorial notebook Kats205: https://github.com/facebookresearch/Kats/blob/main/tutorials/kats_205_globalmodel.ipynb
In the first cell itself
from kats.models.globalmodel
I get the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kats.models.globalmodel' error.
Has there been some refactoring and the tutorials are not
updated? Can someone help me with the correct usage example for Global Model?

Here are screenshots from the Colab session:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The package I get from pip does not have globalmodel. However, when I install from Git repo it works.

Installation command:

`!pip install -qq git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/Kats.git#egg=Kats`

Comment: ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/facebookresearch/Kats.git 'C:\Users\Sarang\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ym2u5u28\kats'